# NullInjectorError: No provider for AppContextService

Tags: angular

I have a service marked as Injectable

```typescript
Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MyService {
    constructor (private appContextService: AppContextService, private http: HttpService) {
}
```

also added MyService and AppContextService to providers in my-service.module.ts

```js
providers: [
    MyService, AppContextService
]
```

but I get an error:

```js
NullInjectorError: No provider for AppContextService!
        error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'MyService', 'AppContextService', 'AppContextService' ] })
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[MyService -> AppContextService -> AppContextService]:
```

I tried to add AppContextService as provider and/or import in my-service.module.ts as well as in app.module.ts, but still get the same error.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Make your `AppContextService` also `providedIn:'root'`

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler - this AppContextService is not mine - this is coming from @microsoft/windows-admin-center-sdk